# Floating text next to picture, maintain position on window resize

Tags: css

```
.pic {
    float:left;
}

.pic > img {
    width:14em;
    height:14em;
}

.data {
    float:left;
    padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
}

.description {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}


<div id="item1">

    <div class="pic"><img src="..." /></div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="description"><p>...long description of the item...</p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How do I prevent the text from jumping to the next line? I want it to always remain right off the image and just wrap as window is resized down.

http://jsfiddle.net/BmLHD/

Comment: Do you know the width of the image?

Comment: image is larger but I'm sizing it down to 14em. I want it to remain proportional to data part

Comment: Can you re-work the markup so that the floated image is in `.data`?

Comment: Then you just need this (with some adjustments for spacing): `<p><img src="" style="float:left" />Here is my description</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove float from the data and add a left margin to the description.

```
.pic {
    float:left;
}

.pic > img {
    width:14em;
    height:14em;
}

.data {
    padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
}

.description {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    margin-left: 14em;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BmLHD/7/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually one of the fundamental building blocks of the internet: the **media object**, so-named and popularized by [Nicole Sullivan](http://www.stubbornella.org/).

```
<div class="media attribution">

  <a href="http://twitter.com/stubbornella" class="img">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/150/100" alt="me" />
  </a>

  <div class="bd">
    @Stubbornella 14 minutes ago
  </div>

</div>

/* ====== media ====== */
.media {margin:10px;}
.media, .bd {overflow:hidden; _overflow:visible; zoom:1;}
.media .img {float:left; margin-right: 10px;}
.media .img img{display:block;}
.media .imgExt{float:right; margin-left: 10px;}
```

You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/46rSh/) and read [more about the media object here](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/).

Note: You can also use [the Flexbox version](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/), which is simpler and more elegant, but you'll need to be sure to address cross-browser support.

Comment: nice cat, yes that's the functionality I want. There's no straightforward CSS method for this? ...odd

Comment: This is as straightforward as it gets, mate.

Comment: ...I shall educate myself then

Comment: One note that I just remembered: there is a simpler way to do this using Flexbox, but you'll need to make sure you address cross-browser support in that case. I added a link to my answer.